# Reset Row_Number (Or Something Like It) Based On a Single Column SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, row-number

I need to populate a column named LBSEQ in a table with a sequential number that resets to 1 each time the value of a column named SUBJID changes. No order has been specified - it's not chronological and it's not dependent on any other column(s) (although there are other columns in the table). So what's wanted is:

```
    SUBJID LBSEQ 
    001        1
    001        2
    001        3
    001        4
    002        1
    002        2
    002        3
    003        1
```

And so on. It seems like I should be able to use ROW_NUMBER() but I can't figure out how to get it to reset to 1 for each new SUBJID. I've searched the question but none of the answers seems to apply to my situation. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to simply use `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT SUBJID, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SUBJID ORDER BY SUBJID) LBSEQ
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: @JeffK627 Please consider accepting this answer if this solved your problem.